# building html in ajax response and displaying that html in modal confirmation

Tags: javascript, ajax

Trying to get some ideas on design part. I want to make ajax call, do server side validation and build the ajax response in html grid and send it over to client and display that in "modal confirmation" dialog and once confirmed in dialog, do the action to commit data to database. Is it possible ?

Comment: " Is it possible ?" If you code it, most likely. So do you now how to do each part individually? Seems like that would be the starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better by generating modal window on client side, and only on confirmation sending ajax request to backend which validates, and updates database or returns error and updates frontend.

It could be done the way you sketched it, but it seems a bit overhead to send two requests.

Comment: but the requirement is to display the data to user after validation (telling him what data is changing from existing values) and get his confirmation to commit to database, I could have done the client confirmation directly using javascript confirm but the user needs to know which data is changing upon form submission.

Comment: well, then the scond part of my answer should interest you "It could be done the way you sketched it"